# what's the difference between /proc/self and /proc/$$?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I used to think that  `/proc/self` and `/proc/$$` are the same in bash terminal, but now I find they are different.

I know `$$` means the current process' pid, and `/proc/self` is the currently running process, it should be bash terminal. why they are different?

```bash
root@VM-73-203-debian:~# echo $$
24415
root@VM-73-203-debian:~# ls -l /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 22  2018 /proc/self -> 24465
root@VM-73-203-debian:~# ls -l /proc/$$
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 May 29 16:23 attr
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$$` is a special bash variable that gets expanded to the pid of the shell.

`/proc/self` is a *real* symbolic link to the `/proc/` subdirectory of the process that is making the call.

When you do `ls /proc/$$` the shell expands it to `ls /proc/pid-of-bash` and that is what you see, the contents of the shell process.

But when you do `ls /proc/self` you see the contents of the short lived `ls` process.

The `$$` is not limited to this usage, you can write `echo $$` to see the bash pid; you can use it to kill yourself, etc.

Comment: I'm being very picky, but the name of the special variable is `$`, the preceding `$` gives the value on expansion as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @cdarke: You are partially right (I've checked the docs to be sure). Actually `$` is not a special variable but a _special parameter_, so `$$` is more like `$1` than `$PID` ;-).

Comment: Agreed.  Historically, variables like `x` were called *named parameters* and `1` etc. were called *unnamed parameters*, rather than *positional parameters* as they are today.  Even in modern `man bash`: "* A parameter is an entity that stores values*".  However few people use the word *parameter* as a general term any more, preferring *variable*.